# Obter dados desse servidor usando curl

Tags: php, libcurl

O meu PHP curl não espera o servidor renderizar os dados de dentro do iFrame que o que me interessa e volta com a página porém sem os dados, pois a requisição ajax leva de 6 a 7 segundos após ó carregamento da página.

Esse é o endereço http://200.101.69.145/segundavia/CodigoDeBarrasParaPagamento/ImprimirFatura?identUc=707139&mesAnoFatmto=01%2F03%2F2015&numeroFd=0

Se essa não é a melhor forma e vc souber de uma melhor, fico grato.

Comment: O curl não vai executar ajax. Ele pega o que tem nativamente na página.

Comment: O que você pode tentar é extrair o endereço interno e fazer nova requisição: http://200.101.69.145/segundavia/Telerik.ReportViewer.axd?instanceID=b69b05929aab4b929073296b785e7285&optype=Report&PageIndex=0&RenderID=d53fdbceeec548868605f39339de9ce9&RenderingFormat=HTML5Interactive

Comment: Mas na primeira requisição o curl não vai esperar o iframe retornar com esses valores, vai voltar apenas com o conteúdo nativamente na página. Ai volto a estaca zero.

Comment: Já espiou os valores codificados em base 64 logo no começo do source? Dê uma olhada no __VIEWSTATE, pode ter algo interessante lá. Se não tiver, pode ser o caso de usar o developer mode do seu browser para estudar de onde vem os valores que você precisa, pois de uma forma ou outra eles estão referenciados no source da inicial (ou em algum recurso carregado por esta). Se seu browser renderiza aquilo, nada impede de você reproduzir o comportamento programaticamente.